# External sorting when indices can fit in RAM

Tags: sorting, disk

I want to sort a multi-TB file full of 20kb records. I only need to read a few bytes from each record in order to determine its order, so I can sort the indices in memory.

I cannot fit the records themselves in memory, however. Random access is slower than sequential access, and I don't want to random-access writes to the output file either. Is there any algorithm known that will take advantage of the sorted indices to "strategize" the optimal way to re-arrange the records as they are copied from the input file to the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reorder array according to sorted index algorithms, but they involve random access. Even in the case of an SSD, although the random access itself is not an issue, reading or writing one record at a time due to random access has a slower throughput than reading or writing multiple records at a time which is typically down by an external merge sort.

For a typical external merge sort, the file is read in "chunks" small enough for an internal sort to sort the "chunk", and write the sorted "chunks" to external media. After this initial pass, a k-way merge is done on the "chunks" multiplying the size of the merged "chunks" by k on each merge pass, until a single sorted "chunk" is produced. The read/write operations can read multiple records at a time. Say you have 1GB of ram and use a 16-way merge. For a 16 way merge, 16 "input" buffers and 1 "output" buffer are used, so buffer size could be 63MB (1GB/17 rounded down a bit for variable space) which would allow 3150 records to be read or written at a time, greatly reducing random access and command overhead. Assuming initial pass creates sorted chunks of size 0.5 GB, after 3 (16 way) merge passes, chunk size is 2TB, after 4 passes, it's 32TB, and so on.